# NSXMLDocument multiple concurrent operations?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, nsxmldocument

I have multiple concurrent XML Document parsing going on in the background through NSXMLDocument and I don't think that it safe, even though the documentation states that NSXMLDocument is thread safe. I am getting this error randomly:

```
Warning: NSBundle NSBundle </System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XQuery.framework> (loaded) was released too many times. For compatibility, it will not be deallocated, but this may change in the future. Set a breakpoint on __NSBundleOverreleased() to debug
```

And documents fail during parsing, if I switch the GCD queue to be serial the problems go away. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here is a sample of the code that is running it (the XML parsing happens in the ForecastDownloader):

```
NSMutableArray *weatherObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_queue_t serialQueue;
serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("us.mattshepherd.ForecasterSerialQueue", NULL);

for (NSDictionary *theLocation in self.weatherLocations) {

    // Add a task to the group
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"dispatching...");
        ForecastDownloader *forecastDownloader = [[ForecastDownloader alloc] init];
        int i = 0;
        WeatherObject *weatherObject = [forecastDownloader getForecast:[theLocation objectForKey:@"lat"] lng:[theLocation objectForKey:@"lng"] weatherID:[[theLocation objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]];

        }
        if(!weatherObject){
            //need to implement delegate method to show problem updating weather
            NSLog(@"problem updating weather data");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"got weather for location...");
            dispatch_sync(serialQueue, ^{
                [weatherObjects addObject:weatherObject];
            });


        }
    });

}
// wait on the group to block the current thread.
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

NSLog(@"finished getting weather for all locations...");
//we will now do something with the weatherObjects
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that looks inherently problematic (except for an extraneous brace, which I'm assuming is a typo/copy+paste error). I suspect the problem is somewhere in `ForecastDownloader`.

Comment: I found a thread(https://devforums.apple.com/message/995664#995664) on apple developer forums where someone else was having the exact problem. I am going to switch to a third party xml library. Not sure if that will help because underneath I think most of them are using libxml.

Comment: I tried touchxml and had the same issues.

Comment: I ended up breaking my background operation into a couple of different queues. One starts the process and kicks off the downloads. When the data returns the xml parsing is sent off on another sync queue so only one xml document is being parsed at once. Not ideal but it seems to increase my performance and remove this error.